# Resources of all known biochemical pathways?

Tags: database, literature

I am looking for a encyclopedia or biochemical pathway atlas of all known or reported pathways. I am very much interested in network and systems biology. Also the references can be open databases, books or whatever. I came to know about a site called [wikipathways](http://www.wikipathways.org) , but it is not opening for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find biochemical pathways on [KEGG pathway](http://www.genome.jp/kegg/pathway.html) for example.

> KEGG PATHWAY is a collection of manually drawn pathway maps representing our knowledge on the molecular interaction and reaction networks for:
>   1. Metabolism 
>       Global/overview   Carbohydrate   Energy   Lipid   Nucleotide   Amino acid   Other amino   Glycan 
>       Cofactor/vitamin   Terpenoid/PK   Other secondary metabolite   Xenobiotics   Chemical structure 
>   2. Genetic Information Processing 
>   3. Environmental Information Processing 
>   4. Cellular Processes 
>   5. Organismal Systems 
>   6. Human Diseases
>   and also on the structure relationships (KEGG drug structure maps) in:
>   7. Drug Development

To illustrate the information you can find there, here is a screenshot: [image: kegg pathway main page]

If you click on kegg atlas, you get an atlas with all metabolic pathways. You can zoom in to great detail en click for further links.

[image: kegg atlas]

If you click on glycolysis or oxidative phosphorylation for example, you will get linked to the following page (see picture). In these detailed schemes of the metabolic pathway, each intermediate can be clicked on, leading to a more detailed page.

[image: kegg glycolysis detail]

[image: kegg oxfos]

Comment: Nice answer, but I am waiting for some more responses before accepting this.

Comment: I don't know if you will get any more :P